# Get a history of CPU/memory usage

Tags: windows, monitoring, memory, central-processing-unit

Is there someway to record Task Managers info about CPU and memory usage to examine later? Or an equivalent tool?

Comment: Now in 2020, win10 Task Manager got [App history] tab showing seeming actual CPU time/cycle usage (whereas procexp CPU time column seems more like time since process start)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Windows Performance Monitor (perfmon) should do the job for you; you can configure it to log to a file, so just enable the counters you need and it'll log as much as you want.

Comment: Any chance you want to write up a more complete answer?  Some steps to follow?

Comment: See answer below by @Matt (and upvote; he deserves it)

Comment: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YHEICA4&l=en-US

Answer (score 19):

- Start > Run > perfmon
- Hit the plus sign next to Performance Logs and Alerts
- Right click System Log and select properties.
- Adjust the sampling times to whatever you like
- When you are done, hit OK then the plus sign at the top of the window.

[This page](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3506526_2/SQL-Server-Performance-Monitor.htm) gives a pretty good step-by-step with screenshots

Comment: Your link was about MS SQL Performance Monitor? Oo

Comment: I don't see a "Performance Logs and Alerts" section on Windows 10.

Comment: "Hit the plus sign next to Performance Logs and Alerts" Where is that?

Comment: To collect the required Perfmon log data in Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 8, Windows 2012 and Windows Vista:

    Click Start > Run, enter perfmon.exe, and click OK.
    Go to the User Defined folder. Click New > Data Collector Set.
    Enter a name for your Data Collector Set.
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2010970

Answer (score 4):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will also show CPU history.

Answer (score 4):

I use PolyMon to monitor these kinds of things.  You can define various "alert" conditions about which you'd like to receive notification, so I get notified if one of my servers is having a problem.

But it also stores all these results in a long term database, so I can look back at the memory usage of server "X" and see it's memory usage trends over the last N days/weeks/months/years.

http://polymon.codeplex.com/

Comment: The link you posted (http://polymon.codeplex.com/) no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using a monitoring solution like zabbix, zenoss to collect and analyse your perf counters.

Answer (score 3):

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) is a great webv based graphing programme. It can graph CPU, memory, disk space, etc, etc. It can also be extended with your own plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Opensource solution Nagios does this also:

- [How do I monitor CPU and Memory usage with Nagios?](https://serverfault.com/questions/73444/how-do-i-monitor-cpu-and-memory-usage-with-nagios)

  http://www.kernelhardware.org/nagios-nsclient-to-monitor-remote-windows-server/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, perfmon ("Performance Monitor" in Control Panel)