# How do I monitor CPU and Memory usage with Nagios?

Tags: linux, monitoring, memory, nagios, central-processing-unit

Is there a plugin that does that? If yes, how do I set it up?

I have Nagios on a single server setup (nagios monitoring the box where it's hosted), so I don't need any fancy way of getting that info from the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a cpu check plugin [here](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_cpu-2Esh/details), you could browse many plugings in [Nagios Exchange](https://exchange.nagios.org/) website, or in [Icinga Exchange](https://exchange.icinga.org/) website. 
Why you don't use cacti for such things, or may be [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) that will permit you easily to monitor the performance of your computers, networks, cpu, memory, file system ...

Answer (score 1):

If the OS is Windows, [this](http://nsclient.org/nscp/) works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to say cacti; nagios sends alerts when some conditions are met

Comment: Nagios can and is also used for monitoring levels.