# Identifying processes causing 100% cpu usage

Tags: windows, monitoring, windows-10, cpu-usage

Some users report high CPU usage on their computers during ordinary activities (like *Teams* calls).

How can I collect a report of processes causing high CPU usage over a few hours?

I would like to use Windows 10 or *sysinternals* tools for this purpose.

I have read [https://serverfault.com/questions/33776/get-a-history-of-cpu-memory-usage/33789#33789] which recommends *PerfMon*, but *Perfmon* requires to add every process you need to monitor explicitly ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiAr8.png)). I need to know *what processes* make heavy use of CPU.

([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiAr8.png)) https://superuser.com/questions/609529/history-of-cpu-usage-for-all-processes

[image: user reported cpu utilisation]

Comment: This seems to be answered already here: [Get a history of CPU/memory usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/33776/get-a-history-of-cpu-memory-usage)

Comment: I read that post before posting, especially [@Matt's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/33789/967397) but I was not able to make use of it. Any tutorial about that specific data collection with _PerfMon_ or any other tool is welcome.

Comment: [This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/609529/history-of-cpu-usage-for-all-processes) contradicts [@Matt's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/33789/967397): _Perfmon requires to add every process you need to monitor explicitly_. This is not the tool for that purpose.

Comment: [Fetch top 10 processes utilizing high CPU as shown in task manager](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/fetch-top-10-processes-utilizing-high-cpu-as-shown-in-task/m-p/1239627). Powershell: `Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property 'CPU' -Descending | Select-Object -First 10`

Comment: On superuser.com: [Log %CPU by Process over time](https://superuser.com/questions/453909/log-cpu-by-process-over-time) (It is using [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from sysinternals)

Comment: Thank you @Luuk for finding this post. I haven't tried _procmon_ yet, but it seems to do what I want.

Comment: @ChristineVACHER Perfmon doesn't require you to add process manually - just launch it from Task Manager or using `perfmon /res` from the command line.